# Husky puppy if I have cats: Yes or no?

Tags: cats, dogs, breeds, husky

I had two dogs, my ex stole them, now I am considering my legal options and also looking at buying two new dogs if things don't go my way.

I have a kitten, I got her to keep me company till I get my dogs (and after :) ). I am also considering getting a husky puppy as one of the two dogs.

Can this work out? Can I teach the husky to leave the kitten alone? My tolerance for random cat body parts in the living room is rather low.

Comment: fwiw I have a greyhound that was taught to chase fluffy rabbits and she now lives with cats. You have a better chance when getting them as pups of course. But there is always that risk when the instinct in the breed is high.

Answer (score 7):

While there might be an argument made for yes, I go with a strong

### NO, don't do it if you love your cat!

According to multiple websites it is not a good idea to have a dog with a high prey drive and other pets in the same house. Those dogs will kill those other pets if they can. And husky's can have a very high drive.

Now, it can be done, having a husky and a cat live together, you can find quite a number of those success stories online. Here is the thing, if the husky (or other dog with high prey drive) decide it's time for fluffy to die, fluffy is dead. Only thing left is a little time.

To use some sobering quotes:

> So if you have cats that you love dearly, I’d avoid having Huskies around at all costs. And that goes for all high prey drive breeds. It is possible to train prey drive mostly out of an individual dog, but it’s hard to do, and personally I’d still never trust the dog around cats or other “prey-looking” pets

- [Jeff Tawater, Professional dog trainer.](https://www.quora.com/Are-huskies-cat-killers)

> No, they will kill cats unfortunately.

- [Kel](https://iheartdogs.com/knowledge-base/breed/huskies/does-your-huskies-get-along-cats/?pageNum=1&totalAns=46)

> The predatory sequence in dogs involves searching, stalking, chasing, catching, biting, killing and eating. In a simple chase response, your husky might not carry out the whole sequence. He may just run after, and then play by gently mouthing the kitty. Whether your husky chases Fluffy just to play or to actually cause harm and pursue the whole sequence, will depend on a variety of factors.

- [Diane Morgan](https://foreverhusky.org/husky-101/huskies-and-cats.html)